# download reports at the background process

Tags: php, mysql, shell, background

Actually i have a file where the downloads happens in xl ..but the table contain huge records and it will take more than 2min..so what i want is run this file in background and when download is finished he gets pop up in front that download is finished ...and so he can go and check in downloads folder..so that he can continue doing other tasks while the download is happening at the back..without making him wait..i googled few websites but was not able to come out with output..
my code for downloading is

```
$fileName = 'Enquires.xls' ;
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");
$flag = false;
$query="";
$query  = "Select ackNo as AckNo, serialNo as SerialNo ,DATE(time) as EnquiryTime, product as Product , customerName as CustomerName , phone as Phone ,query as CustomerQuery,tech as CSO ,raf as RAF_Status,eng_comments as EngineerComments from customerEnquiry where ackNo like '".$locationprefix."%' and DATE(time) between '".$from."' and '".$to."'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');

 while($row =mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if(!$flag) {
      // display field/column names as first row
      echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) ."\r\n";
      $flag = true;
    }
      echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way of doing this is probably to not generate the file the moment the user presses a button. When they press that button, add a record in the database to generate that file and use a cron that runs every minute to get it ready. On your front-end, have a small bit of javascript that polls the server every 30 seconds or every minute to see if there is a new download available. If so, show the popup.

Comment: running cron every min will cause load to the server..is there any alternate

Comment: Running a cron that does nothing but check the database if it needs to do anything generates almost no load. It generates as much load as requesting any other PHP page on your site.

Answer (score 0):

you can do time consuming tasks like this in background. you can look into job queues. Some of these are Redis workers, Gearman or you can even use Message Queues to do this. After processing the job in background, your user has to be notified. you can poll server about the status or push from server to client.